# How do you tell pyximport to use the cython --cplus option?

Tags: c++, python, cython

pyximport is super handy but I can't figure out how to get it to engage the C++ language options for Cython. From the command line you'd run `cython --cplus foo.pyx`. How do you achieve the equivalent with pyximport? Thanks!

Comment: I doesn't look like there is an easier way right now. It would be nice if something like this were added to pyximport. I just tried the commented compiler directives shown at http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#specify-c-language-in-setup-py and they don't seem to work with pyximport.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way to make Cython create C++ files is to use a pyxbld file. For example, create `foo.pyxbld` containing the following:

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename],
                     language='c++')
```

Comment: Just to be clear, will pyximport automagically observe the directives given in foo.pyxbld?

Comment: I am curious about this last point too. How/where are pyxbld files taken into account ?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a hack.

The following code monkey-patches the `get_distutils_extension` function in `pyximport` so that the `Extension` objects it creates all have their `language` attribute set to `c++`.

```
import pyximport
from pyximport import install

old_get_distutils_extension = pyximport.pyximport.get_distutils_extension

def new_get_distutils_extension(modname, pyxfilename, language_level=None):
    extension_mod, setup_args = old_get_distutils_extension(modname, pyxfilename, language_level)
    extension_mod.language='c++'
    return extension_mod,setup_args

pyximport.pyximport.get_distutils_extension = new_get_distutils_extension
```

Put the above code in pyximportcpp.py.  Then, instead of using `import pyximport; pyximport.install()`, use `import pyximportcpp; pyximportcpp.install()`.

Answer (score 5):

A more lightweight/less intrusive solution would be to use `setup_args/script_args`, which `pyximport` would pass to `distutils` used under the hood:

```py
script_args = ["--cython-cplus"]
setup_args = {
    "script_args": script_args,
}
pyximport.install(setup_args=setup_args, language_level=3)
```

Other options for `python setup.py build_ext` can be passed in similar maner, e.g. `script_args = ["--cython-cplus", "--force"]`.

The [corresponding part](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#arguments) of the documentation mentions the usage of `setup_args`, but the exact meaning is probably clearest from the code itself ([here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/efdf996dced075682d86b7e53a12b56b5ebfea38/pyximport/pyxbuild.py#L73) is a good starting point).

Answer (score 3):

You can have pyximport recognize the header comment `# distutils : language = c++` by having pyximport make extensions using the cythonize command. To do so, you can create a new file *filename.pyxbld* next to your *filename.pyx*:

```
# filename.pyxbld

from Cython.Build import cythonize

def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    return cythonize(pyxfilename, language_level = 3, annotate = True)[0]
```

and now you can use the distutils header comments:

```
# filename.pyx

# distutils : language = c++
```

Pyximport will use the make_ext function from your .pyxbld file to build the extension. And cythonize will recognize the distutils header comments.