# How to configure pyximport to always make a cpp file?

Tags: c++, configuration, cython

I want to use c++ functionality most of the time in cython and I find using pyximport very convenient, but making pyxbld configuration file  for each pyx module (as described in [How do you tell pyximport to use the cython --cplus option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620003/how-do-you-tell-pyximport-to-use-the-cython-cplus-option)) is tiresome. Can I configure pyximport to always make a c++ output for all pyx modules?