# Python ctypes LoadLibrary: does it really load a new instance, e.g. so different global variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries, ctypes

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html about `cdll.LoadLibrary`

> This method always returns a new instance of the library.

Does this mean that if the library uses some global variables internally, then each time `cdll.LoadLibrary` is called, it will return a library that uses a new and separate set of global variables?

(This may speak to some misunderstanding of how such shared libraries work... happy to be corrected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `cdll.LoadLibrary` is not something that Python controls, but it depends on the OS on which Python is running. @MarkTolonen answer shows the behavior on Windows, this answer concentrates on Linux (and MacOs).

`cdll.LoadLibrary` uses [`dlopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) for loading of the shared objects, thus the behavior of `dlopen` is what we need to analyze.

Let's take look at the following C-code (`foo.c`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
static int init();

//global, initialized when so is loaded:
int my_global = init();

static int init(){
    printf("initializing address %p\n", (void*)&my_global);
    return 42;
    
}

extern "C" {
void set(int new_val){ my_global = new_val;}
int get() {return my_global;}
}
```

compiled with `g++ --shared -fPIC foo.c -o foo.so`. I use C++ rather than C, so every time the global variable `my_global` is initialized, it is logged to stdout (this would not be [that straight forward in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3025050/5769463)).

After some preparation:

```py
import ctypes

def init_functions(dll):
    get = dll.get
    get.argtypes = []
    get.restype = ctypes.c_int
    set = dll.set
    set.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
    set.restype = None
    return get, set
```

we observe the following behavior:

```py
#first load:
get, set = init_functions(ctypes.CDLL("./foo.so"))
# initializing address 0x7f5ca4a8102c
print(get())   # 42
set(21)
print(get())   # 21
```

so far as expected: global variable was initialized, and we can read/write it. Now second load:

```py
get2, set2 = init_functions(ctypes.CDLL("./foo.so"))
```

Ups, we don's see logging of the initialization, that means...

```py
print(get2())  # 21
```

the global variable was not initialized anew. That is the expected behavior of `dlopen`: once a shared object is loaded, it is never reloaded but reused. This is the reason why e.g. `pyximport` or `%%cython`-magic use different [names for resulting shared-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172547/5769463).

To really create new version we copy the shared object `foo.so` to `foo.so.1`, and now:

```py
# load copied shared object:
get3, set3 = init_functions(ctypes.CDLL("./foo.so.1"))
# initializing address 0x7f5ca487102c
print(get3())    # 42
```

We can see, the global variable was initialized, but it is another address, i.e. not the old variable, as can be easily checked:

```py
print(get())    # 21 - still the old value.
```

Util now, the behavior is more or less the same on Windows and Linux, however on Linux we could use symbol interposition to ensure that the same global variable is used.

Normall CPython uses `dlopen` with `RTLD_LOCAL`, i.e. no interposition of symbols is used, by using `RTLD_GLOBAL`, i.e.

```py
...
#first load:
get, set = init_functions(ctypes.CDLL("./foo.so", mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL))
# initializing address 0x7fd01efc102c
...
```

`mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL` will be ignored on Windows.

The first difference can be seen for

```py
...
# load copied shared object:
get3, set3 = init_functions(ctypes.CDLL("./foo.so.1"))
# initializing address 0x7fd01efc102c
...
```

The same address as for "foo.so" is used also "foo.so.1" - due to `RTLD_GLOBAL` the symbols `n` from both shared objects were interposed.

And now:

```py
print(get3())  # 42
print(get())   # 42
```

That means, the old global variable was reinitialized.

---

While funny, I would not recommend to depend on these details - it is just too clever, too brittle and not portable: it is really easy to introduce memory leaks or crashes.

One should accept, that in general, global variables cannot be reinitialized (in a portable way) by reloading a shared object.

Normally, one would like to avoid that global variables are interposed and ensure that they have internal linkage in the shared object (e.g. by making them static or using [`hidden`-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216452/5769463) while compiling) and thus don't get interposed even if loaded with `RTLD_GLOBAL`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a new *Python* instance of type `ctypes` wrapper, but references the same DLL.  This is easy enough to test:

test.c:

```c
__declspec(dllexport)
int global = 7;

__declspec(dllexport)
int increment() {
    global += 1;
    return global;
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
print(dll)
print(c_int.in_dll(dll,'global'))
print(dll.increment())
print(c_int.in_dll(dll,'global'))

dll2 = CDLL('./test')
print(dll2)
print(c_int.in_dll(dll2,'global'))
print(dll2.increment())
print(c_int.in_dll(dll2,'global'))
```

Output below.  Note the global variable keeps incrementing, the instance addresses are different but the handles (actually the virtual base addresses of the loaded DLL) are the same.

```
<CDLL 'C:\test', handle 7ff81aad0000 at 0x2362f0dbee0>
c_long(7)
8
c_long(8)
<CDLL 'C:\test', handle 7ff81aad0000 at 0x2362f0dbeb0>
c_long(8)
9
c_long(9)
```