# Cython reload with pyximport reload_support not working

Tags: python, ipython, cython, spyder

There are a number of questions on SO about reloading Cython files in IPython (I'm using Spyder).  Here's my implementation that appears to check all the boxes from other questions:

```
from importlib import reload
import pyximport
import sys
pyximport.install(reload_support=True)

try:
    del sys.modules['cython_test.ctest']
    del ctest
except:
    pass

import cython_test.ctest as ctest
ctest = reload(ctest)

ctest.test()
```

However, it doesn't work and I have to restart the kernel to get an updated version of the file.

In case it's relevant, here's how I'm generating the `.so` file:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

file = os.environ.get("CYTHONIZE_FILE", "")
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(f"{file}.pyx"))
```

And I would call this in the command line:

```
CYTHONIZE_FILE=ctest python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After reload you need to once again import. For an explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172547/5769463

Comment: That explanation hinted at what the problem was.  See my answer.  So the `.so` file is needed only for running in the command line?  Any explanation as to why one way works in IPython and the other way works in the terminal?

Comment: if you generate so-file by yourself, you should not use pyximport (it generates extensions in cache, i.e. our of place) as its purpose to build extensions on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is apparently with building the file and creating the `.so` file.  If I don't do this at all (i.e., completely remove the `.so` file and restart the kernel), the code I have works.