# Wrt. Anaconda Python 3.4 and Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Sorry for being new to Anaconda (and Cython).

I used Anaconda 64-bit Python 3.4 Windows.

Where did Anaconda do all these settings for Cython? I have a test code called `cy_test.pyx` as follows:

```
import numpy as np

cpdef double [:] func():
    cdef double [:] a = np.arange(10.)
    return a
```

And then, Instead of

```
import pyximport, numpy
pyximport.install(setup_args={"script_args":["--compiler=mingw32"], "include_dirs":numpy.get_include()})
```

I only need to run `import pyximport; pyximport.install()`. Then I can use

```
import test_cy
a = test_cy.func()
print(list(a))
```

It just worked, without me telling it to include the `numpy.get_include()`.

My question is, where is this being set? There should be a configuration file somewhere, right?

-Shawn

Comment: @Veedrac Sorry - I changed it and now there is only 1 question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import numpy` is just a regular import. Unless you do `cimport numpy` Cython doesn't treat this specially (it doesn't import headers or other compile-time files), thus there's nothing special to include.

I very much doubt there is any special feature Anaconda is doing.

If you want to configure `pyximport`, you can make a `pxybld` file, [such as when you want to support C++ with `pyximport`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620003/how-do-you-tell-pyximport-to-use-the-cython-cplus-option).

Comment: `import numpy` itself is just a regular import. The part that is weird is it is not necessary to add `np.get_include()` to `"include_dirs"` in the `pyximport.install()`, as stated in the question.

Comment: OMG you are right! I am sorry that I did not first understand your answer. I apologize for the downvote and will cancel it once I am allowed (after 2 hours).

Comment: No hard feelings; glad I could help :).

Comment: @ShawnWang Something to note here, in the past, I've had to set up a 'distutils.cfg' file in <Python_dir>/Lib/distutils to get pyximport working. Anaconda already has that set up with an entry that tells Python's distutils to use MinGW for compilation by default.