# Using C++ STL maps in Cython

Tags: maps, cython

I'm trying to use a map in a Cython class but the Cython compiler raises an error.

Here is an example demonstrating my problem and the error reported by Cython.

**Cython file pyx**

```
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.utility cimport pair
from libcpp.string  cimport string

cdef class MyDict:
      cdef:
            map[string, int] components

      def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            self.components[key] = value

      def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self.components[key]
```

**Python file**

```
from pyximport import install
install()

from dic_class import MyDict

m = MyDict()

m["home"] = 5

print m["home"]
```

**Error reported by Cython**

> fatal error: utility: No such file or directory

Comment: Indent properly; and if these are C++ maps note that in tags and subject line.  We don't want to confuse these with Python's own `map` function.

Answer (score 3):

You've not done anything to set it up to compile as C++ rather than C. The C compiler will be unable to find the C++ standard library (hence the "no such file or directory" error).

You need to [tell pyximport to use C++ instead of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620003/how-do-you-tell-pyximport-to-use-the-cython-cplus-option) by setting up a .pyxbld file. Alternatively you could use [setup.py in C++ mode](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#specify-c-language-in-setup-py) instead of pyximport.