# Compiling cython with gcc: No such file or directory from #include "ios"

Tags: python, cython

Given a file `docprep.pyx` as simple as

```
from spacy.structs cimport TokenC

print("loading")
```

And trying to cythonize it via

```
cythonize -3 -i docprep.pyx
```

I get the following error message

```
docprep.c:613:10: fatal error: ios: No such file or directory
 #include "ios"
          ^~~~~
compilation terminated
```

As you can tell from the paths, this system has an Anaconda installation with Python 3.7. `numpy`, `spacy` and `cython` are all installed through `conda`.

Comment: `ios` is a c++-header (I don't know where it comes from, but they should have called it `#include <ios>`), so you probably need to build it as c++, i.e `cython --cplus ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C++ STL maps in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241269/using-c-stl-maps-in-cython)

Comment: @ead Thanks, that was the problem. Then I needed to fix 4 additional problems: 1) compile the `.cpp` file, not the `.c` file 2) use cython with `--embed`  3) Add `main` function to python program 4) use `-lpython3.7m` instead of `-lpython3.7`. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidW This is not a duplicate. This questions is about standalone compilation. There's no `setup.py` or Python file calling into the `pyx`.

Comment: Why is ios stuff included? I do not get it

Comment: @TheUnfunCat It is something that cython includes

Comment: In my case `--cplus` did not worked, I needed to add `language="c++"` in the setup.py file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<ios>` is a c++-header. The error message shows that you try to compile a C++-code as C-code.

Per default, Cython will produce a file with extension `*.c`, which will be interpreted as C-code by the compiler later on.

Cython can also produce a file with the right file-extension for c++, i.e. `*.cpp`. And there are multiple ways to trigger this behavior:

- adding `# distutils: language = c++` at the beginning of the `pyx`-file.
- adding `language="c++"` to the `Extension` definition in the `setup.py`-file.
- call `cython` with option `--cplus`.
- in IPython, calling `%%cython` magic with `-+`, i.e. `%%cython -+`.
- for alternatives when building with `pyximport`, see [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7620003/5769463).

Actually, for `cythonize` there is no command line option to trigger c++-generation, thus the first options looks like the best way to go:

```
# distutils: language = c++

from spacy.structs cimport TokenC
print("loading")
```

---

The problem is that `spacy/structs.pxd`   uses c++-constructs, [for example vectors](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/f6078d866ad5548be4a279ec690ba493d92015f0/spacy/structs.pxd#L6) or anything else cimported from `libcpp`:

```
...
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
...
```

and thus also c++-libraries/headers are needed for the build.

Comment: I think the `distutils: language` option is usually the way to go - the choice of language is really required the pyx file and therefore having to put the selector anywhere else is just making it harder to track what's happening. (It's definitely useful to list all the options though)

Comment: distutils is deprecated https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils-deprecated

Answer (score 10):

In my case, it worked using @mountrix tip, just add the `language="c++"` to your setup.py, an example:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy


extensions = [
    Extension("processing_module", sources=["processing_module.pyx"], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()], extra_compile_args=["-O3"], language="c++")
]

setup(
    name="processing_module",
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```

Comment: You can also add the following line at the beginning of you `.pyx` file: `# distutils: language = c++`