# Cython: fatal error: 'ios' file not found

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471655/compiling-cython-with-gcc-no-such-file-or-directory-from-include-ios) and [Using C++ in Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#specify-c-language-in-setup-py) but have had no success in getting my code to compile. My understanding was that including `language="c++"` would do the trick, but this does not seem to be the case.

**cytest.pyx**

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map

cdef unordered_map[int, int] umap
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension(
    "cytest",
    sources=["cytest.pyx"],
    language="c++"
)
setup(
    name="cytest",
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext)
)
```

Running `python setup.py build_ext -i` yields:

```
Compiling cytest.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing cytest.pyx
/home/miniconda3/envs/cyenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/CyTest/cytest.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
running build_ext
building 'cytest' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/home/miniconda3/envs/cyenv/include -arch x86_64 -I/home/miniconda3/envs/cyenv/include -arch x86_64 -I/home/miniconda3/envs/cyenv/include/python3.7m -c cytest.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/cytest.o
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
      [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
cytest.cpp:624:10: fatal error: 'ios' file not found
#include "ios"
         ^~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Do you have the headers for `stdlibc++` installed? On Ubuntu `libstdc++-6-dev` might be a likely header that provides the necessary files.

Comment: `gcc` doesn't seem to be the proper wrapper for C++ compiler.

Comment: Hmm it appears that it was due to having conflicting versions in different Conda environments. Upgrading my packages resolved the issue.

Comment: You are on macos, gcc is in reality clang and the warning tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: The link inside ```This question already has an answer here ...``` worked perfectly.