# From a .pyx file create .cpp file and not a .c file

Tags: cython, cythonize

I am new to cython. I have a project file `project_file.pyx` which I would like to manually create a `.cpp` file with.

I have tried `cython project_file.pyx` but this produces project_file `.c`.  However I would like to produce the file `project_file.cpp`.

How can I do this? I'm running a Linux environment.

Comment: This answer lists all the options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838304/5769463

Answer (score 1):

You should put this line at the top of your .pyx file:

```
# distutils: language = c++
```

This should compile it in to a .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--cplus` flag.

`cython --cplus project_file.pyx`