# Cython include error for catkin_pkg setup

Tags: python, c++, cython, ros, include-path

I use the following code to from [here](https://github.com/longjie/ros_cython_example) in the **setup.py** to make a python wrapper of a c++ class:

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['hw_interface_pkg'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    requires=['std_msgs', 'rospy'],
)
setup(**setup_args)
```

the error I get is:

```
/src/cython/hw_interface.c:482:
/include/remote_hw.h:6:10: fatal error: array: No such file or directory
 #include <array>
          ^~~~~~~
```

which is the very first include in the header. Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620003/how-do-you-tell-pyximport-to-use-the-cython-cplus-option), [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471655/compiling-cython-with-gcc-no-such-file-or-directory-from-include-ios), and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241269/using-c-stl-maps-in-cython), the main solution seems to be adding `language="c++"` in the arguments. However, this did not solve the problem for me and the code from above is also rather different from the one used in those threads. (it uses "generate_distutils_setup" instead of  "cythonize" or "Extension").

In addition other than the standard c++ includes like `#include <array>`, there are also other ones which I'm not sure if the setup will find them. Can someone suggest a possible solution for this? could this issue be actually originating from the CMakelists.txt details?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding the "set_source_files_properties" like the following in the child CMakeLists.txt.

```
... 
set_source_files_properties(hw_interface.pyx PROPERTIES CYTHON_IS_CXX TRUE)
cython_add_module(hw_interface hw_interface.pyx ../fibonacci.cpp)
...
```